# Middleware en archivo de rutas funciona pero no en controladores

Tags: laravel, users-roles

Estoy intentando filtrar los métodos por roles en los respectivos controladores.

Si coloco la restricción en el archivo web.php funciona bien:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:SuperAdmin', 'namespace' => 'Schedules'], function () { ...
```

Pero si lo intento poner en el controlador, todos los usuarios pueden acceder a todos los métodos sin restricciones, por lo que no funciona:

```
class ScheduleController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('role:Usuario')->only('index');
        $this->middleware('role:SuperAdmin')->only('index', 'edit');
        ...
```

¿Qué está pasando? Creo que no entiendo cómo trabaja esto...

Gracias!

[EDITO PARA PONER MÁS DATOS]
Estoy usando (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) Spatie Permission para gestionar roles y permisos.

En el archivo app/Http/Kernel.php en la sección de $routeMiddleware lo tengo declarado:

```
'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
```

Lo que no entiendo es por qué en las rutas si funciona y en el controlador no...

Comment: Hola jakama, te encuentras en StackOverflow en Español, si no traduces tu pregunta posiblemente acabe cerrada.

Comment: No me di cuenta, lo siento. Ahora mismo.

Comment: Debería funcionar con esa sintaxis, es probable que haya un policy o algún otro middleware que esté por encima.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar el middleware "role", primero debes crearlo y definirlo en app/Http/Kernel.php dentro de los middlwares de tu aplicacion ($routeMiddleware)

por ejemplo

```
‘role’ => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
```

Puedes crear el middleware con el comando de artisan "php artisan make:middleware CheckRole" y el metodo te quedaria algo asi:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
        return redirect('home');
    }
return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Perdón, creo que no me expliqué porque no di toda la info. Estoy usando (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) Spatie Permission. Edito la pregunta para poner más datos.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar la solución... Bueno, más bien de entender el problema.

Si pongo:

```
$this->middleware('role:Usuario')->only('index');
$this->middleware('role:SuperAdmin')->only('edit');
```

No significa que "Usuario" no pueda utilizar el resto de métodos, simplemente, no podrá usar 'edit' porque está especificado que sera role 'SuperAdmin'

Entonces, por ejemplo, si pusiera esto:

```
   $this->middleware('role:Usuario')->only('index');
   $this->middleware('role:SuperAdmin')->only('index');
```

'Usuario' no podría usar 'index' porque, aunque en principio le decimos que sí, después le decimos que tiene que ser 'SuperAdmin'.

Como último ejemplo:

```
   $this->middleware('role:Usuario|SuperAdmin')->only('index');
   $this->middleware('role:SuperAdmin')->only('edit', 'destroy');
```

En este caso, tanto 'Usuario' como 'SuperAdmin' podrán usar el método 'index' pero sólo 'SuperAdmin' podrá usar 'edit' y 'destroy'.

Ojo, el resto de métodos como 'update' o 'storage', al no haberse definido, podrán usarlos todos...